# Reloading Data in a datatable on form submit

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a web page that has 2 parts (1) a form with certain inputs (search filters) (2) DataTable (https://datatables.net/) that reacts to submit.

Is there a way I can reload or refresh the DataTable on form submit? User can look at the data; tweak the search criteria in form and resubmit.

For now I am pre populating the DataTable with default data on page load. How can I make it reach to submit() button and reload / redraw itself using the form data?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dtQryResults').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "order" : [[2, "desc"]],
            "ajax":{
                url :"./include/mysql/qryresults.php?tx=default", // json datasource
                type: "GET",  // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
                error: function(){
                    $("#dtQryResults").css("display","none");
                }
            }
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: Have you've solved your problem this time?

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving this by serializing form inputs to a variable and then using that variable in DataTable settings. For now it is working but I haven't done much testing yet.

```
var searchFilter = "tx=default"; //this is for default criteria

$("#queryform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();    
    searchFilter=$('#queryform').serialize();
    $('#dtQryResults').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

Changed "ajax" to the following:

```
"ajax":{
    url :"./include/mysql/qryresults.php", // json datasource
    type: "GET",  // type of method - GET/POST/DELETE
    data: function( d ) {
            d.tx=searchFilter;
        },
    error: function(){
        $("#dtQryResults").css("display","none");
    }
},
```